# Can String_Split be used in a VIEW?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, view

I have a table with multiple IP addresses in a single column separated by commas, I am using the following query and it works perfectly when used in a select, but when I try to make a view it doesn't work, it gives me the error

> Invalid Object name 'string_split'.

Can `string_split` be actually used in views? I can use an SP but it would really help that its a view because I need to make multiple joins to this result with other views and a `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT 
      distinct [ColumnA]
      ,[ColumnB]
      ,cs.value as IPs
  FROM [table] as A
  cross apply string_split( 
    replace(
    replace(
            replace(
                replace([value], '-', ',')
                , ';', ',')
            , '_', ',')
            , ' ', ',')
    , ',')cs
  where A.[value] <> ''
  and cs.value like '%.%.%.%' --and cs.value like '%host%'
  order by 3
```

The data usually also has a lot of garbage text, like system- or other words so I filter them out with the replaces so the `string_split` also splits this and then I use where to get rid of everything that isn't an IP

Data example

| ColumnA | ColumnB | IPs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SomeText | MoreText | 10.10.10.10,10.10.10.11,10.10.10.12 |

Result example when using as a query

| ColumnA | ColumnB | IPs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SomeText | MoreText | 10.10.10.10 |
| SomeText | MoreText | 10.10.10.11 |
| SomeText | MoreText | 10.10.10.12 |

Comment: FYI, ordering by ordinal column number is not recommended as best practice. Use the column name.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You have an error in your SQL, your inner replace should reference column [IPs]

Comment: You can definitely use `string_split` in a view see [dbfiddl](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b7a8760f07f64bf98fb6ae6e9aeece03). If I was you I would move the replace functionality into a separate `cross apply` so you can debug it separately - rather than doing it all in a single statement.

Comment: Your database needs to be on compatibility level 130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query works fine in a *view* as follows. Note, SQL Server 2017 introduced *Translate* which you can use instead of the nested Replace functions

```
create or alter view test as 

select ColumnA, ColumnB, cs.[value] as IPs
from t
cross apply string_split( translate(IPs, '-;_ ', ',,,,'),',')cs
where cs.[value] <> ''
and cs.value like '%.%.%.%' 

GO

select * from test
order by IPs
```

Comment: Sadly our database is SQL Server 2016, but translate seems awesome! Thanks! apparently what I was doing wrong was the order by, when trying to use the view editor it would give me errors for other stuff, but now that I tryied to manually create the view with CREATE it told me to discard the order by and it finally let me

Comment: I would recommend not using the built in GUI designers. Views cannot contain order by unless you also specify *top* since the result of a view is a derived table and tables have no ordering, always explicitely state the ordering criteria in the query. and now you have (another) reason to expedite that upgrade ;-)